# How to get Rembg to keep shadows on objects

Tags: python, image, rembg

I'm trying to set up rembg to keep shadows on objects when the background is removed.

Need this result:

[image: Need this result]

Code:

```
from os import listdir, mkdir
from os.path import isfile, join, getmtime
from shutil import copy2
from datetime import datetime
import cv2
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
from rembg import new_session, remove
from PIL import Image

def get_time():
    now = datetime.now()
    dt_string = now.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
    return dt_string


def read_barcode(image):
    img = cv2.imread(image)
    detected_barcodes = decode(img)
    if not detected_barcodes:
        return ""
    else:
        bc = detected_barcodes[0]
        return bc.data


def process(session, _image, *, size=None, bgcolor='#f6f6f6'):
    if size is not None:
        _image = _image.resize(size)
    else:
        size = _image.size
    result = Image.new("RGB", size, bgcolor)
    out = remove(_image, session=session, alpha_matting=True, alpha_matting_foreground_threshold=100, alpha_matting_background_threshold=20, alpha_matting_erode_size=15)
    result.paste(out, mask=out)
    return result


rsession = new_session("u2net")
AI_ACTIVE = False
AI_PHOTO_COUNT = 2

WORKING_PATH = "./INPUT/"
OUTPUT_PATH = "./output/"
print("Loading...")

print("[SETUP] Укажите, будет ли использоваться REMBG. 1 - да, 0 - нет:")
ans = input()
if ans == "1":
    AI_ACTIVE = True
elif ans == "0":
    AI_ACTIVE = False
else:
    print("[SETUP] Некорректный формат ответа. Установлено значение по умолчанию: REMBG не используется")

if AI_ACTIVE:
    print("[SETUP] Укажите количество фотографий для товара, которые будут обработаны REMBG:")
    ans = input()
    limit = int(ans)
    AI_PHOTO_COUNT = limit
    print(f"[SETUP] Установлен лимит {AI_PHOTO_COUNT}")

with open("ai_logs.txt", "a", encoding="UTF-8") as log:
    print(f"[INFO] [{get_time()}] Процессор запущен. Используется AI: {AI_ACTIVE}. Чтение файлов из папки...")
    log.write(f"[INFO] [{get_time()}] Процессор запущен. Используется AI: {AI_ACTIVE}. Чтение файлов из папки....\n")

    files = [f for f in listdir(WORKING_PATH) if isfile(join(WORKING_PATH, f))]
    files = [join(WORKING_PATH, f) for f in files]
    files.sort(key=lambda x: getmtime(x))

    print(files)
    print(f"[INFO] [{get_time()}] Обнаружено {len(files)} файлов. Обработка...")
    log.write(f"[INFO] [{get_time()}] Обнаружено {len(files)} файлов. Обработка...\n")

    current_queue = []

    for file in files:
        new_file = ""

        if file.split(".")[-1] in [
            "jpg",
            "jpeg",
            "png"
        ]:
            print(f"[INFO] [{get_time()}] Добавлен файл: {file}")
            log.write(f"[INFO] [{get_time()}] Добавлен файл: {file}\n")

            current_queue.append(file)
            product_id = read_barcode(file)
            try:
                product_id = bytes(product_id).decode('ASCII')
                product_id = product_id[7:]
            except:
                pass

            if product_id != "":
                current_queue.pop()
                print(f"[INFO] [{get_time()}] Файл {file} содержит штрихкод: {product_id}")
                log.write(f"[INFO] [{get_time()}] Файл {file} содержит штрихкод: {product_id}\n")
                product_images = current_queue
                current_queue = []

                print(f"[INFO] [{get_time()}] Формируется папка {product_id}...")
                log.write(f"[INFO] [{get_time()}] Формируется папка {product_id}...\n")

                mkdir(f"{OUTPUT_PATH}{product_id}")
                index = 0
                for image in product_images:
                    index += 1
                    new_img_name = f"{index}.{image.split('.')[-1]}"
                    print(f"[INFO] [{get_time()}] Копирование {image} в ./{product_id}/{new_img_name}")
                    log.write(f"[INFO] [{get_time()}] Копирование {image} в ./{product_id}/{new_img_name}\n")
                    copy2(
                        image,
                        f"{OUTPUT_PATH}{product_id}/{new_img_name}"
                    )

                    if index-1 < AI_PHOTO_COUNT and AI_ACTIVE:
                        print(f"[INFO] [{get_time()}] Запущена AI-обработка изображения {index} для товара {product_id}...")
                        log.write(f"[INFO] [{get_time()}] Запущена AI-обработка изображения {index} для товара {product_id}...\n")

                        img = Image.open(f"{OUTPUT_PATH}{product_id}/{new_img_name}")
                        res = process(rsession, img, size=img.size, bgcolor="#F6F6F6")
                        res.save(f"{OUTPUT_PATH}{product_id}/{new_img_name}")

                        print(f"[INFO] [{get_time()}] AI-обработка изображения {index} для товара {product_id} завершена")
                        log.write(f"[INFO] [{get_time()}] AI-обработка изображения {index} для товара {product_id} завершена\n")

                print(f"[INFO] [{get_time()}] Папка {product_id} сформирована")
                log.write(f"[INFO] [{get_time()}] Папка {product_id} сформирована\n")
```

[Image for test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ppebp.jpg)

[Image for test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX3wd.jpg)

[Image for test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHotR.jpg)

I've tried changing the threshold settings, but that doesn't help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.